# Bootstrap buttons added dynamically render differently to those declared in markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Like the title says..

I have markup like this:

```
.spancenter {
    margin:0 auto !important; 
    float:none !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="spancenter">
            <input id="btnSave" name="btnSave" class="btn" type="button" value="Save" />
            <input id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" class="btn" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I get that HTML via AJAX (ie. literally say `$('#divWrapper').html(thehtml);` it renders differently:

[image]

(Top one is from AJAX, bottom one is static markup)

In Firebug they look identical.

Why do they render differently?

Comment: Open up chrome -> dev tools -> elements tab -> computed styles to see what's actually different between the two.

Comment: Can you provide an example that replicates the issue?

Comment: Are we just talking about the space between them in the bottom vs the top?

Comment: Yeah. And the buttons look slightly different. Trivial I know but I just wondered what Bootstrap is doing - maybe something in the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs are inline elements thus in HTML like in the example above there will be a space between them. There are several ways how to get rid of it, and one of them is to write HTML without spaces, e.g.

```
<input type="button"
/><input type="button" />
```

or

```
<input type="button" /><input type="button" />
```

Your AJAX response is probably a string without any spaces, so it's like using this hack. That's why buttons are different.

As for a general look — they are the same. Just take the buttons from the bottom row and put them on top of the top raw — you will see that it's an illusion.